# How to get the number of decimal digits from a double in Java? (Ex: 2.34 => 2 , 2.340 => 2 , 0.921 => 3)

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, double

Title is self-explanatory. What is a good way, with just math preferably, to get the number of digits from a Java double?

```
123 => 0
1.12 => 2
1.0001 => 4
2.340000 => 2
0.10 => 1
```

I have a double d = 0.320 for example.

As far as I know, for the compiler / jvm / computer:

```
System.out.println(0.0100000 == 0.01); // prints true...
```

Comment: How is 0.10 a length of 1?

Comment: 0.10 is actually 0.1. Same thing for the compiler / computer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Guess - sginificant digits of the fractional part

Comment: Zeros can be significant too.

Comment: @jdphenix The only issue is 0.1 isn't precisely representable in binary... so if we count binary digits it would be infinite. How many digits are in decimal when we divide `1/3`?

Comment: ElliottFrish `System.out.println(0.0100000 == 0.01); // prints true...`

Comment: @chrisapotek `System.out.println(0.10 + 0.10 + 0.10); // prints 0.30000000000000004`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Same thing for `System.out.println(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1);` but that does not change the fact that 0.100000 == 0.1

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - that's a huge non-issue.  The OP wants something that would return `1` for `0.3`, and `17` (if I can count) for `0.1+0.1+0.1`.

Comment: @chrisapotek Okay, here's another `System.out.println(0.05 + 0.05 + 0.05 == 0.15); // prints false`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch still a non-issue.

Comment: @DavidWallace Still only commenting.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: `System.out.println(2147483647 + 2147483647)` prints `-2`; what are you getting at?

Comment: @tmyklebu When OP says *to get the number of digits from a Java double*, it kind of matters what kind of precision you're after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get the amount after the dec:

```
 Double d = 123.9343;
 String[] div = d.toString().split("\\.");
 div[0].length();   // Before Decimal Count
 div[1].length();   // After  Decimal Count
```

***Explanation***: You first turn the double into a string and use the `split` function to split the string from the `.` 
Once it is in 2 pieces you can then find the length of the string easily with the `length` function.

Comment: You have to be careful with scientific notation there, no? Ex: 9E-1 ?

Comment: Yes but if you try with 2.340 it'll return 3. But chrisapotek wants it to return 2.

Comment: @TheCazziator33: Try it, it returns 2.

Comment: Are you sure scientific notation will not be an issue there? Ex: 9E-1 ?

Comment: Wait are you asking if this function well accept `9E-1` as an input? Because It shouldn't

Comment: toString() never produces scientific notation, right?

Comment: Are you expecting the values to come in as a `string` or `double only`? Because if java recognizes 1e-9 as 0.00000000001 (as a double) then it should be fine.

Comment: @chrisapotek Incorrect - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29

Comment: @jdphenix toString can produce scientific notation or not?

Comment: @chrisapotek Try it and see. `Double.valueOf(0.0000000018).toString()`

Comment: @chrisapotek or read the link that jdphenix kindly provided, which very clearly states whether or not `toString` can produce scientific notation.

Answer (score 11):

Short version: Use `BigDecimal` and it's `scale()` method. Initialize however you wish.

Long version:

You specifically mentioned that you prefer the solution you use to be

- "Math only" (ambiguous but I can guess what you mean)
- Get the number of digits from a `double`, presumably the fractional part (based on your expected output)

Here is a solution that uses `java.math.BigDecimal` to do so:

```
List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>() {{
    add(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0000000018));
    add(BigDecimal.valueOf(123));
    add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.12));
    add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.0001));
    add(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.340000));
    add(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.10));
}};

for (BigDecimal bd : list) { 
    System.out.println(bd + " --> " + bd.scale());
}
```

Outputs:

```
1.8E-9 --> 10
123 --> 0
1.12 --> 2
1.0001 --> 4
2.34 --> 2
0.1 --> 1
```

Note that instantiating `BigDecimal` from `double` like this will eventually give you surprising results. Consider the `scale()` of `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1)`, which is `17`. This is because `0.1` (and most other ~ 97% of numbers in range) cannot be represented exactly by `double`, which introduces rounding errors in calculations.

Also note that using `scale()` functions where solutions involving manipulating the results of `toString()` would fail. [`Double.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) is well defined, and can produce a range of outputs beyond what one may think of as "decimal notation" of a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no useful notion of "the number of digits of a Java `double`" consistent with the results you gave.  A `double` is a binary floating-point number, not a decimal floating-point number, and, for example, the Java `double` 1.12 is actually the number `1.12000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875`, which has 50 digits after the decimal point before all the repeating zeroes.

Comment: That's because you are adding more decimal digits than it is supported, dude. They are being discarded by the compiler. `System.out.println(1.1200000000000001); // prints 1.12`

Comment: @chrisapotek: There is no coherent notion of "the number of decimal digits that are supported."  The compiler is not 'discarding" some but not other decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `BigDecimal` class which specifies a precision. Everything else is just a hack.

[This is required reading as a computer scientist](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), and you must read it to understand why your question is so broken.

Comment: I do not think you need to read all of Goldberg's paper to understand what binary floating point is.

Comment: And his question isn't broken. It's just a question.

Comment: @rocksNwaves after googling around a bit that's apparently a more obscure phrase than I've thought. There's one ELL [https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/what-does-broken-question-mean](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/what-does-broken-question-mean) asking about a *different* time I used it, and there's no wiki page on it unlike "abuse of notation", "begging the question" and other philosophy-related phrases. That being said it means the question is ill-posed; it rests on an invalid premise in this case that doubles "have" a number of digits in any sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String num="1122345.67823";
    System.out.println(num.indexOf("."));
    System.out.println(num.length());
    //This is what u need//
    System.out.println("\n" +"Decimal digits: " + (num.length()-num.indexOf(".")-1));
    System.out.println("\n" + "Integer Digits: " + (num.length() -(num.length()-num.indexOf("."))));
```

P.S if num is Integer instead of String just use the " String.valueOf(num)" to convert it.

Answer (score -1):

**The number of decimal digits in a double is 15.9.  Period.**  (I'll let you figure out how to treat the 0.9.)

If you have a the floating-point number 1.00000000000001, you have no idea (without further information) whether the "1" on the right end of that number is "information" or "noise".  Similarly with 0.9999999999999 -- is it really 1.0, or are all those 9s significant?  **You don't know** without some information about the precision of the calculations/measurements than went into producing the number.

It is common to format the number out to N digits and then "trim" strings of zeros (or, with rounding, 9s) on the right, but this is at best an educated bet.  At worst it's throwing away critical data.

Comment: Certain floating-point values cannot be represented without using 17 digits, but not all 16-digit decimal numbers have unique representations.  Thus, the number of meaningful digits is in some cases only 15, and in some cases 17, though it's usually 16.

Answer (score -2):

I won't give you the code, just the approach.  One approach is to print the number into a string then use regular expression on that string.  Get the portion of the string after the decimal place and count the numbers until you get to a 0.  There are corner cases but you can take care of that.  One thing though, some numbers cannot be represented exactly, such as 4/3, so the number of the decimal places theoretically is infinite.  But if you print to a string, you're capping the number of decimal places which makes it easy to count.  Just know that if you cap at N decimal places and your counter returns N there's a little doubt whether it's exactly N decimal places or infinite.  If you have trouble implementing this approach show me what you've got and where you're stuck and I can help you further.